# IIB HTTP Request Node - Intermittently throwing SSL socket error while connecting on rest service hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

HTTP Request node connecting to a third party REST API, which is hosted on AWS intermittently throwing "A timeout error occurred whilst performing an SSL socket operation ". I would like to know why is it happening intermittently and how to find root cause of this issue. While we invoking services in OnPrem instead of AWS all good , when we swith to AWS he are facing the following issue

HTTP Request Node Settings: Protocol - TLSv1.2 ,HTTP Version 1.1

IBM Integration Bus v10.0.0.8 and  IBM ACE 12.01

POST //url**** HTTP/1.1 ;A Web Service request has detected a SOCKET error whilst invoking a web service located at host ****t;A timeout error occurred whilst performing an SSL socket operation
BIPmsgs Number :3166